# How to migrate Hibernate Integrator from 4 to 5 (install a Hibernate interceptor)

Tags: java, hibernate, wildfly, wildfly-10

We are using a Wildfly application server and are currently migrating from 8.2.0 to 10.1.0.

With WildFly 8.2 (Hibernate 4.3) we could install a global Interceptor for all Sessions using a Hibernate `Integrator`.

```
public class MyIntegrator implements Integrator {
    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MyIntegrator.class);

    @Override
    public void integrate(Configuration configuration, SessionFactoryImplementor sessionFactory, SessionFactoryServiceRegistry serviceRegistry) {
        logger.info("Install GlobalInterceptor in " + configuration.getProperty("hibernate.session_factory_name"));
        configuration.setInterceptor(new GlobalInterceptor());
    }

    ...
}
```

This does not work anymore with Wildfly 10.1 (Hibernate 5) since the API has changed. Instead of the `Configuration` Hibernate now passes a `Metadata` instance into `integrate`.

I couldn't find any information on this in the migration guides.

Thank you for any hints!